# Как изменить высоту ActionBar?

Tags: android, actionbar

Всем привет.
1) Тему приложения не трогал; оставил тот, который по умолчанию - AppTheme.
2) К Activity стили не применял, почти всё устраивает.

Не устраивает только высота заголовка активности, нужно поменьше.

Стал копать getSupportActionBar. Нашёл getHeight и обрадовался, что наверняка есть, парный ему, метод setHeight или что-то похожее. Не тут-то было, даже похожего не нашёл. Может плохо смотрел?

Есть темы, в которых высота ActionBar устраивает, но в них не устраивает всё остальное, и они кстати почему-то не устанавливаются (приложение вылетает при переходе на рассматриваемое Activity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте новый xml файл в папке res/values и напишите там такой код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>   
    <style name="Theme.MyOwnSize" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarSize">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">40dp</item> 
    </style> 
 </resources>
```

И для вашей Activity в манифесте поставьте тему

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MyOwnSize"
```

Comment: Здесь поднять вопрос об `ActionBar`, а не о `Toolbar`

Comment: Видимо, как вариант, предлагается использовать Toolbar вместо ActionBar...

Comment: Сейчас изменю ответ для ActionBar

Comment: Изменил ответ...

Comment: Если честно, у меня почему-то не сработало по-Вашему - на рассматриваемом Activity вылетает. НО... Вы показали мне ключевые две строчки, которые я пристроил куда мне надо, и вуа-ля =). Спасибо, и галочка Вам.

Comment: И Вам спасибо :)